# How Side Navigation component can be used in UI5 to show the content?

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to use Side Navigation component in UI5. From the below picture you can see a modal dialog, I have used side navigation to get the items in the left. when ever I select something from the list, corresponding content should be visible on the right.

Can someone please suggest me on how it can be achieved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need some form of Splitter e.g. sap.ui.layout.Splitter

Take a look a this [little Demo](https://jsbin.com/zogenamini/edit?html,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"/>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

       <script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.layout" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"></script>
        <script>

            var dialogModel = {
                RateCategory_ID: {
                    id: "RateCategory_ID",
                    label: "Rate Category",
                    type: "MultiSelect",
                    values: [{
                        key: "ST",
                        value: "ST",
                        selected: true
                    }, {
                        key: "DT",
                        value: "DT",
                        selected: false
                    }]
                },
                Approval_Filter: {
                    id: "Approval_Filter",
                    label: "ApprovalFilter",
                    type: "SingleSelect",
                    values: [{
                        key: "Separate_Filter",
                        value: "Separate",
                        selected: true,
                    }, {
                        key: "Last_Approval_Filter",
                        value: "Last Approval",
                        selected: false
                    }]
                }
            };

            var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            model.setData(dialogModel);

            var oParentList = new sap.m.List({
                mode: "SingleSelectMaster",
                items: {
                    path: "/",
                    template: new sap.m.StandardListItem({
                        type: "Active",
                        title: "{label}"
                    })
                },
                selectionChange: function(event) {
                    var oBindingContext = event.getSource().getSelectedItem().getBindingContext();

                    oMembersList.setBindingContext(oBindingContext);

                    oSelectedItemsList.setBindingContext(oBindingContext);
                    oSelectedItemsList.getBinding("items").filter(new sap.ui.model.Filter("selected",sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ,true));

                }
            });

            oParentList.addEventDelegate({
                onAfterRendering: function() {
                    // check if nothing is selected
                    if (this.getSelectedItem() === null) {
                        var items = this.getItems();

                        // check if there are items
                        if (items && items.length > 0) {
                            this.setSelectedItem(items[0], true);
                        }
                    }
                    this.fireSelectionChange();
                }
            }, oParentList);


            var oMembersList = new sap.m.List({
                mode: "{type}",
                includeItemInSelection: true,
                modeAnimationOn: false,
                items: {
                    path: "values",
                    template: new sap.m.StandardListItem({
                        type: "Active",
                        title: "{value}",
                        selected: "{selected}"
                    })
                },
                selectionChange: function(event) {
                    var oBindingContext = event.getSource().getBindingContext();
                    oSelectedItemsList.setBindingContext(oBindingContext);
                    oSelectedItemsList.getBinding("items").filter(new sap.ui.model.Filter("selected",sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ,true));
                }
            });

            var oSelectedItemsList = new sap.m.List({
                mode: "Delete",
                modeAnimationOn: false,
                visible: {
                    path: "type",
                    formatter: function(type) {
                        return type === "MultiSelect";
                    }
                },
                items: {
                    path: "values",
                    template: new sap.m.StandardListItem({
                        title: "{value}",
                    })
                },
                delete: function(oEvent) {
                    model.setProperty(oEvent.getParameters().listItem.getBindingContextPath() + "/selected", false);
                    oMembersList.fireSelectionChange();
                }
            });

            var variablesVBox = new sap.m.VBox({
                items: [
                    new sap.m.Label({
                        text: "Variables"
                    }),
                    new sap.m.Label({
                        text: ""
                    }),
                    oParentList
                ],
                layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.SplitterLayoutData({
                    resizable: false
                })
            });

            var membersVBox = new sap.m.VBox({
                items: [
                    new sap.m.Label({
                        text: "Available Members"
                    }),
                    new sap.m.Label({text: ""}),
                    oMembersList
                ],
                layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.SplitterLayoutData({
                    resizable: false
                })
            });

            var selectedMembersVBox = new sap.m.VBox({
                items: [
                    new sap.m.Label({
                        text: "Selected Members"
                    }),
                    new sap.m.Label({text: ""}),
                    oSelectedItemsList
                ],
                layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.SplitterLayoutData({
                    resizable: false
                })
            });


            var splitter = new sap.ui.layout.Splitter({
                contentAreas: [variablesVBox, membersVBox, selectedMembersVBox]
            });
            splitter.setModel(model);

            var okButton = new sap.m.Button({
                text: "OK",
                press: function(event) {
                    oDialog.close();
                }
            });
            var cancelButton = new sap.m.Button({
                text: "Cancel",
                press: function(event) {
                    oDialog.close();
                }
            });
            var oDialog = new sap.m.Dialog({
                title: "Global Variables",
                content: [splitter],
                buttons: [okButton, cancelButton],
                contentWidth: "70%",
                contentHeight: "70%"
            });

            var oButton = new sap.m.Button({
                text: "Open dialog",
                press: function() {
                    oDialog.open();
                }
            }).placeAt("content");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="sapUiBody">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`sap.tnt.SideNavigation` has to be placed inside `sap.tnt.ToolPage` in order to work properly. But the ToolPage control is meant to take the full width and height of the page, not only a part of it, like it would if placed inside Dialog. Therefore using this controls to achieve what you need is not possible.